# Python 3D array filled with values from equation

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I want to generate a python array that is filled with values from a given equation.
Eg. I have the values x = 20, y = 30 and z = 4 and the equation v = 7*x + 20*y - 3*z

I want to calculate each possible point (eg v0 = 7*0+20*0-3*0, v1=7*1+20*0-3+z, v2=7*2+20*0-3*0,...) so that for each possible point in the "cube" I have the calculated value (according to the coordinates)

I really hope that makes sense...

I think its easier than it sounds and my head is just thinking way too complicated

I did try with different loops and functions like meshgrid, np.indices but it doesnt work and theres either always an error or numbers that do not make any sense...

Comment: I did try to do it in this form
import numpy as np

x = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y = (0, 1, 2, 3)
z = (0, 1, 2)


arg = ((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2))

def function(arg):
    a = arg(0) + arg(1) + arg(2)
    return a

resultat = []
for something in arg:
    resultat.append(function(arg(something)))

But my head is just dead and I dont know how to make it work

Comment: Welcome in Stackoverflow. This is a place to help people write their own code.
Please show some piece of code [MRE] so we can help. See welcome [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to deal with any equations or expression evaluations is to use the sympy module
you can define symbols(algebraic variables) and substitute values to evaluate them.

as per my understanding of your question you just need the values of V in an array, for this we can use a simple list and substitute values of V using list comprehension or a simple for loop append will do.

you can semi hard code the values that need to be substituted in V by using a dictionary or tuples or list as shown below, i have considered a cuboid definition but you can consider a cube too.

at the end if you want to convert the list into a numpy array if you want to

so here is my code

```
from sympy import symbols as sym
#defining symbols and expressions
x=sym('x')
y=sym('y')
z=sym('z')
v=7*x+20*y-3*z

#defining points of cuboid
cubePoints=[]
for i in range(0,5):
 l,w,t=i,i,i
 cubePoints.append({x:0,y:0,z:0},
         {x:0,y:0,z:t},
         {x:0,y:w,z:t},
         {x:0,y:w,z:0},
         {x:l,y:0,z:0},
         {x:l,y:0,z:t},
         {x:l,y:w,z:t},
         {x:l,y:w,z:0})

#evaluating the expression values
array=[v.subs(values) for values in cubePoints]
print(array)
```

Comment: that is awesome, i just have the problem, that I need not only the values for 5 but for 0 to 5 for each l, w and t
making it not fixed but having kind of a loop where theres always 1 added until l,w and t = 5

Comment: wrap the entire cube point definition inside another for loop ranging from 0 to 5 and instead of list comprehension append the dictionary elements , the final array will contain all of the values and every 8 elemental values belong to a particular l,w,t